# What does this Vagrantfile configuration do? What does the "vagrant up" statement do in this specific Apache Storm example?

Tags: vagrant, apache-storm, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I am new in Vagrant and in Apache Storm.

I am following an online course where show the following situation.

1. There is an Ubuntu virtual machine installed on Virtual Box
2. On the host machine (the same where is installed Virtual Box and that run the guest Ubuntu VM) it is installed Vagrant.

In the tutorial first download from GitHub a directory that contains some project by this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/Udacity/ud381
```

that create this directory on my host Windows machine:

```
C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\workspaces\Real-Time\ud381
```

As you can see entering in the previous github repository this directory contain a **Vagrantfile** that contain:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "udacity/ud381"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5000, host: 5000
end
```

From what I have understand the **Vagrantfile** represent the Vagrant configuration and I think that it represent the link with the Ubuntu guest VM that I have previously installed on **VirtualBox** (I have installed it by myself but I don't know if it is correct).

What exactly represent the previous configurations into my **Vagrantfile**?

I think that **udacity/ud381** is the VM name on VirtualBox but I am not sure about it.

Then in the tutorial show that, using the shell, I have to enter into the directory that contain the **Vagrantfile** (this: C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\workspaces\Real-Time\ud381) and perform this statement:

```
vagrant up
```

it seems that begin to download something (it is very slow). What is it doing? What is it downloading?

Comment: It's downloading the `box`. You might want to have a read of the [Vagrant getting started guide](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**udacity/ud381** is a reference to a [vagrant box](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html) located on atlas.hashicorp : https://atlas.hashicorp.com/udacity/boxes/ud381

when you do `vagrant up` with this Vagrantfile it does create a new VM using the box you specified, if the box is not already in your system, it will try to download, hence it appears to be slow. Further `vagrant up` with this same box will be much faster as it will create the VM from a local box.

If you plan to use vagrant, you should let it manage the VM and do not create the VM in VirtualBox yourself (there are some ways to make this link but thats not trivial and not sure if its supported). Ideally try not to start VirtualBox once when you do a full cycle with vagrant (init, up, ssh ...) and you will see how smooth it is

Comment: So what you exactly mean? that Vagrant is downloading a Box that inside it contain the VM? (So is it downloading something that contain the VM?). But how this VM will be started? Automatically by Vagrant or, after that the box is downloaded, manually by VirtualBox?

Comment: yes vagrant needs a box to be able to create a new VM - vagrant takes care of all communication with the VM (start, stop ...)